How to remove provided scope dependencies from gemnasium maven dependency scan in gitlab
In gitlab pipeline, I am using
include:

template: Jobs/Dependency-Scanning.gitlab-ci.yml

On running the pipeline, it is included maven dependencies having "provided" scope as well in the security vulnerability report.
Is there any way to exclude the provided scope dependencies?
I have tried using GEMNASIUM_IGNORED_SCOPES: "provided" in the pipeline but it does not work. Also, tried setting DS_INCLUDE_DEV_DEPENDENCIES as false in the CI-CD variables but it also does not work

Adding this in Pipeline script worked for me:
gemnasium-maven-dependency_scanning:
  variables:
    GEMNASIUM_IGNORED_SCOPES: "provided,test"


